# Remote debugger hangs with latest release of IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I support a large app which requires me to make extensive use of IntelliJ's remote debugger.  On Friday, I upgraded to the latest version of IntelliJ (2018.3),  which appears to have issues around remote debugging. The remote debugger just hangs, I cannot step through the code or do anything, without restarting the app. Sometimes it works just for one iteration and hangs on the second iteration. I ruled out the possibility of it being a problem with having the 'Memory' view expanded (it is minimized).

I found that version 2018.1.6 Build #IU-181.5540.7 is the oldest working version.  Already in 2018.1.7 (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.7 (Ultimate Edition)  Build #IU-181.5540.23, built on November 12, 2018),  the remote debugger is not working properly...

Any ideas what may be happening?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544799. If it's not the case, submit a bug to YouTrack with the logs and the thread dumps (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544899).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now understand what happened:  In the older version of IntelliJ, I had JRebel plugin installed but not enabled. When I upgraded to 2018.3,  the JRebel plugin became enabled automatically and I didn't realize what happened.  After deactivating JRebel, the remote debugger started working again.  Now I'm on the latest version IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-183.4588.27, built on November 28, 2018 and everything is working smoothly.

Comment: Today I had the same problem but JRebel was not installed. Fortunately I found the solution in the comments on the link https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799 CrazyCoder sent above: I deleted all my breakpoints. Now I can add some new and it works as before. I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: yes, deleting all the breakpoints can also help, and i usually do that first before starting to despair :)